# XML DTD mandatory attribute options

Tags: xml, dtd

I'm trying to construct a DTD for the following element (As part of a larger DTD for a full XML file):

```
<contact>
        <base>019374627</base>
        <mobile primaryContact="true">0861029388</phone>
        <email>john@lennon.com</email>
</contact>
```

I'm just confused because this `contact` element must contain at least one element, and there must be exactly one element inside `contact` that has a `primaryContact="true"` attribute.

How could this be represented with a DTD? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be expressed in a DTD.

In a DTD, you can specify that the `contact` element must contain a `mobile` element. You can also specify that a specific subelement (`mobile`, for example) must have a `primaryContact` attribute with a (fixed) value of "true".

But it is not possible to just declare that an element must have at least one subelement, or that the `primaryContact` attribute must occur on exactly one subelement. All allowed subelements must be explicitly declared. An element's validity cannot depend on an attribute attached to another element.

FWIW, the constraints *can* be expressed in a [Schematron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schematron) schema:

```
<sch:schema xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron">

  <sch:pattern name="Check children of 'contact'">
    <sch:rule context="contact"> 
      <sch:assert test="*">
        'contact' must contain at least one element
      </sch:assert>
      <sch:assert test="count(*[@primaryContact='true']) = 1">
        'contact' must contain exactly one element where @primaryContact='true'
      </sch:assert>
    </sch:rule>
  </sch:pattern>

</sch:schema>
```

Answer (score 1):

With a slight variation in you DTD you might be able to express what you need. The idea is to wrap the required content in a new *element*. This allows you to specify on `contact` that it needs to have one `primary` element:

```
<contact>
    <primary><mobile>0861029388</mobile></primary>
    <base>019374627</base>
    <email>john@lennon.com</email>
</contact>
```

Your DTD might look like this:

```
<!ELEMENT contact (primary, (mobile|base|email)*)>
<!ELEMENT primary (mobile|base|email)+>
<!ELEMENT mobile (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT base (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT email (#PCDATA)>
```

Or, to reduce redundancy and increase maintainability:

```
<!ENTITY % contact_field "mobile|base|email" >
<!ELEMENT contact (primary, (%contact_field;)*)>
<!ELEMENT primary (%contact_field;)+>
<!ELEMENT mobile (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT base (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT email (#PCDATA)>
```